# Creating an MD5 Hash of A ZipFile

Tags: python

I want to create an MD5 hash of a `ZipFile`, not of one of the files inside it. However, `ZipFile` objects aren't easily convertible to streams.

```
from hashlib import md5
from zipfile import ZipFile

zipped = ZipFile(r'/Foo/Bar/Filename.zip')
hasher = md5()
hasher.update(zipped)

return hasher.hexdigest()
```

The above code generates the error :`TypeError: must be convertible to a buffer, not ZipFile`.

Is there a straightforward way to turn a `ZipFile` into a stream?

There's no security issues here, I just need a quick an easy way to determine if I've seen a file before. `hash(zipped)` works fine, but I'd like something a little more robust if possible.

Comment: Just access it as an ordinary file. You only need to use `zipfile` if you want to access files within the archive.

Comment: Ha! I knew that this couldn't be as hard as I was making it look! If you want to post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function should return the MD5 hash of any file, provided it's path (requires `pycrypto` module):

```
from Crypto.Hash import MD5


def get_MD5(file_path):

    chunk_size = 8192

    h = MD5.new()

    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            chunk = f.read(chunk_size)
            if len(chunk):
                h.update(chunk)
            else:
                break

    return h.hexdigest()

print get_MD5('pics.zip') # example
```

**output:**

```
6a690fa3e5b34e30be0e7f4216544365
```

[Info on pycrypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto)

Answer (score 8):

Just open the ZipFile as a regular file. Following code works on my machine.

```
from hashlib import md5
m = md5()
with open("/Foo/Bar/Filename.zip", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read() #read file in chunk and call update on each chunk if file is large.
    m.update(data)
    print m.hexdigest()
```